# Laravel / Eloquent WHERE NOT SUBQUERY

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I`m having trouble to setup a negative condition like such:

```
WHERE NOT( "last_day" "<=" $first_day OR "first_day" "<=" $last_day)
```

My query builder looks like this atm:

```
$query = $query->where(function ($query) use ($first_day, $last_day) {
   $query->where('last_day', '<=', $first_day);
   $query->orWhere('first_day', '<=', $last_day);
});
```

I would like it to be as such :

```
$query = $query->whereNot(function ($query) use ($first_day, $last_day) {
  $query->where('last_day', '<=', $first_day);
  $query->orWhere('first_day', '<=', $last_day);
});
```

To recap: I want an OR statement inside a negative WHERE condition. How can I accomplish this?

source : http://baodad.blogspot.nl/2014/06/date-range-overlap.html

Comment: I don't think your operands are right. What exactly are you checking for?

Comment: They indeed are not, I`ll edit, and completely specify

Comment: Basicly what I`m trying to do is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the logic

```
$query = $query->where(function ($query) use ($first_day, $last_day) {
   $query->where('last_day', '>', $first_day);
   $query->where('first_day', '>', $last_day);
});
```

Comment: I don`t think the logic is the same, it does not qualify: "Allen's interval algebra" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allen%27s_interval_algebra

Comment: Change : $query->where('first_day', '>', $last_day); to   $query->where('first_day', '<', $last_day); and its correct, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233652/eloquent-mysql-statement-where-nota-or-b

Answer (score 0):

Went with reverting constraints according to answer found here: [Eloquent MYSQL statement : WHERE NOT(A OR B)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233652/eloquent-mysql-statement-where-nota-or-b)

```
$query = $query->where('last_day', '>', $first_day)->where('first_day', '>', $last_day);
```